# White Screen edges on Macbook Pro 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, gpu

I have a MacBook Pro 15 inch, 2014 model, with 2 GPUs: Intel and NVIDIA 750M.

Last Monday I turned it on and I noticed that the screen is white as you can see in the picture.

The problem is that when I keep the Mac turned on for some time (>2 hours) the screen goes back to normal without white edges.

When I turn it off and keep it turned off for a while, then turn it on again it becomes white again and I must wait >2 hours so I can see my screen without this whiting effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a well known hardware problem.

I had the same Problem after falling asleep on my Macbook, the pressure destroyed the Display.

You should contact Apple and get the Display replaced.

Comment: There is no apple in my country :(

Comment: You can contact the Apple Support online (https://support.apple.com).